# Control not returning after self.close() encountered in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to make a UI using PyQt. It has a very basic working. when the script is run on terminal, a dialog box asking for name should open and close when **Ok** is pressed. However, I am unable to return the control from the Qt app.

My code is as follows:

```
class Interactive(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Interactive,self).__init__()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
            self.setGeometry(300,300,290,150)
            self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')
            self.show()

            self.inputdialog =  QtGui.QInputDialog()
            self.inputdialog.move(50,50)

            text, ok = self.inputdialog.getText(self,'Input Dialog','Enter Your Name:')
            #self.text = text
            if ok:
                self.text = text    
                print text
                self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Interactive()
    #app.exec_()
    if app.exec_():
        sys.exit()
        print "somerandomtext"
```

The `print text` from within the class is working, but my test string `"somerandomtext"` is not and the program is not ending.

I have looked at similar questions at So, but none seemed to address the same problem.Do I have to make another handler for this?

Comment: Because you are using sys.exit() before print. So its never going print anything fore sure after exit.

Comment: If the sys.exit () had been executed , the program would have terminated , and as I have already said,  the program is not terminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the application will quit automatically when the last top-level window closes, but that is preventedf from happening in your example because you do not allow the event-loop to get started properly.

There are numerous ways to re-structure your example to avoid this problem, but probably the simplest is to use a timer like this:

```
class Interactive(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Interactive,self).__init__()
        # delay initialization
        # self.initGUI()
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Interactive()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, obj.initGUI)
    app.exec_()
    print "somerandomtext"
```

**PS**:

The reason why `deleteLater()` sort of works in the other answer is because it posts a deletion event to the event queue (which will be processed once the event-loop has properly started). The `close()` method doesn't post an event in this way, and so the application doesn't get the chance to quit automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.  Can you  describe what you meant by "not allowing the event loop get started properly" .does it have to do with system configuration like ram etc ?

Comment: No, it's just that your `initGUI` tries to do too much before the event loop gets going. If you had a button on the main window that opened the diaog, it would also solve the problem. It's just a matter of allowing a small delay before the user starts interacting with the gui.

Comment: Ok. But earlier I tried a similar example without input dialog , added a push button and wrote self.close () in its event handler and it worked fine . Why here then?

Comment: The way you start the input dialog means it uses its own event-loop (internally, Qt opens the dialog with `exec()`). This allows you to interact with the dialog, but it also it prevents the main application event-loop from starting. The closing of the main window happens *after* the dialog exits its event-loop, but *before* the main event-loop starts. If you opened the dialog using its `show()` method, it would not start its own event loop, and the problem would not occur. A small (asynchronous) delay would also allow the main event-loop to get started before the main window is closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explaination.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ok:
                self.text = text    
                print text
                self.deleteLater()
```

Should terminate the app

Comment: Please check http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#deleteLater and http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#close you will see the difference.